# expo build error eas build -p android --profile preview sdk 49

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, eas

I am building expo build using command eas build -p android --profile preview and eas.json config as
getting the error.

I have tried tried npx expo-doctor it is saying all check completed and no error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us what the exact error is but I have faced kind of this problem in Expo and the thing caused the problem was **expo-cli package**.

```
npm uninstall expo-cli
```

Remove **expo-cli** locally and try again. If it does not work then take a screenshot of **error** or edit the post with **error output** to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building with an Android folder, that is if you ran eject command or expo prebuild and your error contains something like R package app theme, Then make sure that the namespace in android/app/build.gradle is correct and that ReactNativeFlipper.java in the release folder is created with the correct package name. Otherwise change it manually.